# Regex or function for pulling <a></a> out of a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working with React & Typsescript. I have a block of text that comes from an API and I need to extract the  tag from it so I can put an onClick on it for reporting information (know when someone clicks on it). I was thinking of creating a variable which I can set the a tag to and then put an onclick on it. Here is the block of code:

```
"<div id="wfText">
<p>In order to view your available regional sports network and local channels, you have to be located within your billing zip code.</p><ul><li>Sometimes even though you are located within your billing zip code, your internet provider routes the internet service through a different zip code. The DIRECTV NOW app uses the zip code provided by them to determine location. 
</li>
</ul>
<div>
<a id="link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#par1" class="kbarticle-expandable collapsed"> <span style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle;">View Available Channels</span> </a><div id="par1" class="collapse" style="background: none; height: 0px;"><p>If you are registering in a different zip code than your billing zip code, to see what channels are available for you to view:</p><ol><li>Go to 

<a target="_blank" href="https://www.directv.com/rsnlocalchannels">directv.com/rsnlocalchannels</a>

</li><li>Enter your billing zip code and review the channels available. </li><li>Enter the zip code for the area you are registered in and look for networks that match the ones available with your billing zip code. </li></ol><p>If you don&#39;t see the same network on both lists then there will not be a local channel available for that network.</p></div></div><p>Issue resolved?</p>"
```

I need to get that link which comes dynamically and put an onClick on it which links to another function. Does anyone know of a regex or way of manipulating this string to extract the  and all its contents? Need some help

Comment: Use https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio

Comment: I can't use any 3rd party packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function createElement(html, elem = "div") {
  const element = document.createElement(elem);
  element.innerHTML = html
  return element
}

const html = `<div id="wfText">
<p>In order to view your available regional sports network and local channels, you have to be located within your billing zip code.</p><ul><li>Sometimes even though you are located within your billing zip code, your internet provider routes the internet service through a different zip code. The DIRECTV NOW app uses the zip code provided by them to determine location. 
</li>
</ul>
<div>
<a id="link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#par1" class="kbarticle-expandable collapsed"> <span style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle;">View Available Channels</span> </a><div id="par1" class="collapse" style="background: none; height: 0px;"><p>If you are registering in a different zip code than your billing zip code, to see what channels are available for you to view:</p><ol><li>Go to 

<a target="_blank" href="https://www.directv.com/rsnlocalchannels">directv.com/rsnlocalchannels</a>

</li><li>Enter your billing zip code and review the channels available. </li><li>Enter the zip code for the area you are registered in and look for networks that match the ones available with your billing zip code. </li></ol><p>If you don&#39;t see the same network on both lists then there will not be a local channel available for that network.</p></div></div><p>Issue resolved?</p>`

console.log(createElement(html).querySelector("a"))
```